# SD card won't format

Tags: 16.04, sd-card

SD card won't format for unknown reason. I've burned Remix OS to try it but after that the SD card isn't formatting anymore. It shows this error:

```
Error formatting volume
Error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Comment: Run `sudo lsblk -i /path/to/sd/card` an post it...

Answer (score 1):

**It is probably enough to overwrite existing data with zeros in the first megabyte**, where the bootloader and the partition table reside. This is much faster and causes much wear of the memory cells compared to wiping the whole device. After that you can format the card without problem (as long as the card is not damaged physically).

**mkusb-dus** can do this job automatically. Either wipe the first megabyte or restore the drive to a standard storage device with an MSDOS partition table and a FAT32 file system. See these links,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your SD card in a camera, then try using an application called **Disks** to format the card.

1. Open it up and click on the menu button (three small bars) at the top right corner.
2. Choose **Overwrite existing data with zeroes (Slow)** next to *Erase* and **Compatible with all systems and devices (MBR / DOS)** next to *Partitioning*.

   [image: format screenshot]
3. Click on **Format...**.
4. When it is finished formatting, take the card out of your computer and insert it into your camera.
5. Most cameras have a **"Format Memory card"** option. Navigate to it, press **ok** and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the SD card was simply "Lock"ed by the adapter. After unlocking it, the problem is resolved. See an example of the lock switch in https://kb.sandisk.com/euf/assets/images/faqs/1102/id1102_extreme4.gif